# How to record microphone to mp3 in Termux on Android?

Tags: audio, termux

I'm interested to try out Termux command line on Android to record microphone audio to mp3. I've tried running different commands but without much effect. Can anyone pinpoint correct example command to start recording of the microphone, to mp3, at a default location, for example downloads folder? (This is on Android Oreo)

termux-microphone-record

-d           Start recording w/ defaults

-f     Start recording to specific file

-l    Start recording w/ specified limit (in seconds, unlimited for 0)

-e  Start recording w/ specified encoder (aac, amr_wb, amr_nb)

-b  Start recording w/ specified bitrate (in kbps)

-r     Start recording w/ specified sampling rate (in Hz)

-c    Start recording w/ specified channel count (1, 2, ...)

-i           Get info about current recording

-q           Quits recording

from https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-microphone-record

Answer (score 2):

Termux does not (yet) appear to support recording directly to mp3 format. To get an mp3, you'll need to convert your recording using ffmpeg.

AWR Wide format has good quality for speech recording.

```bash
# Begin recording
termux-microphone-record -e awr_wide -f filename.amr

# Stop recording
termux-microphone-record -q

# Convert to mp3
ffmpeg -i filename.amr filename.mp3
```

Comment: How are you supposed to use the `termux-microphone-record -q` when `termux-microphone-record -e awr_wide -f filename.amr` is running?

Comment: It is running as a daemon so ure able to write to the console, it will automatically be stopped after 15-sec by default, if u dont type the limit explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

**The Below command will record for 10 sec and save your file.mp3 in your termux Home directory.**

```
termux-microphone-record -d -f filename.mp3 -l 10
```

Comment: Your answer creates an mp4 audio file (better known as m4a)

Comment: On my device, the program just keeps running indefinitely, instead of for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 1. the app for Android Termux.Api (i did from F-droid) and 2. the linux package (pkg install) 3. i had to give permission to microphone for termux.Api

after it records and stops automatically with -l.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: This however seems to be enough to be considered an answer. Pleas review and [edit] according to [answer] as much as possible.